# Typescripts , The JS file generated by command line with is not correctly,variables are defined in the end of the file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Typescripts about HTML5 project, when I use vs2013 IDE to compile the project, the JS files will be generated correctly, but when I use command line to compile the project, the JS file variables will be define in the end of the file, is anyone know, why it's happened?

batch scripts:

*`SET buildDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE
"%buildDir%\DEVENV" "%projectDir%\xxx.sln" /rebuild "Release|Any CPU" /useenv`*

JS file:

```
var Greeter = (function () {
function Greeter(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.element.innerHTML += "The time is: ";
    this.span = document.createElement('span');
    this.element.appendChild(this.span);
}
Greeter.prototype.start = function () {
};

Greeter.prototype.stop = function () {
    clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
};
return Greeter;
})();
window.onload = function () {
   var el = document.getElementById('content');
   var greeter = new Greeter(el);
   greeter.start();
};
var ListBo1x = System.Windows.Controls;
var Action1 = System.Action;
var Date1 = System.DateTimeConventions;
```

Comment: Maybe post the original TS code from which this was generated?

Comment: @Daniel Yesterday, I found the root cause, because all the import variables are defined in one TS file, eg. a.ts, and all the TS file will be generated one JS file, if we use the command line to compile the TypeScript project,  if the a.ts file is not in the head of the .csproj file which marked with <ItemGrop></ItemGrop>, the compiling tool would be compiled files one by one, and when met the a.ts file, the import variables will be insert into output JS file,  so the import variables will be defined in the middle or end of the output JS file.

Comment: So I tried to  move the a.ts file to the head of the <ItemGrop></ItemGrop> item in the .csproj file, and it's worked, but I still don't know why use IDE can generate JS correctly even though we don't do this change.
 ex
<ItemGrop>
a.ts
.....
</ItemGrop>

Comment: I don't know if that is a VS bug or not, but may be worth noting that in the example you posted it wouldn't actually cause a problem. Everything in that JS output is in order that works fine. Even if (say) `Date1` was referenced inside `Greeter.start`, it will not be a problem. The order only matters if a function is actually *executed* before the initialisation of a variable/proeprty that it tries to read.